# Showing random variables are uncorrelated but not independent.

Tags: probability, independence, correlation

> Let $\Omega = (0,1), F = $ Borel sets, $P = $ Lebesgue measure. Show $X_n(\omega) = \sin(2\pi \omega), n = 1, 2, \ldots$ are uncorrelated but not independent.

To show they are uncorrelated, I found that 
$$E[X_n(\omega)] = \int_{0}^{1} \sin(2\pi n \omega) d\omega = 0,$$
and therefore
$$E[X_n - E[X_n]]E[X_m - E[X_m]] = 0.$$

I'm a little bit stuck on showing that they're not independent. I know I have to find $B_i \in F$ such that
$$P(\cap \{X_i \in B_i\}) = \prod P(X_i \in B_i).$$
(Can this be over countably many $B_i$, or does the definition only allow for finitely many?)

My original thought was essentially that of the linked answer, namely,

> Consider $X_1$ and $X_2$:
>   $$
> P(X_1,X_2\in[0,1])=P([0,1/4])=\frac{1}{4}
> $$
>   but
>   $$
> P(X_1\in[0,1])=\frac{1}{2},\\
> P(X_2\in[0,1])=\frac{1}{4}.
> $$

However, I believe this is wrong because shouldn't $P(X_2 \in [0,1]) = 1/2$, since $\sin(4\pi \omega)$ is nonnegative on $[0,1/4]$ and $[2/4, 3/4]$?

Comment: The equation following "and therefore" is not what you need to show to show that the variables are uncorrelated.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Shouldn't have the second E. Still, not super hard to show they're uncorrelated.

Comment: The problem isn't the second $E$. The problem is that $E[X_nX_m]$ doesn't occur in any of the terms. What you've written is automatically zero if the individual expectations are zero. The covariance is $E[X_nX_m]-E[X_n]E[X_m]$, which can be non-zero for $E[X_n]=E[X_m]=0$.

Comment: I meant to compute that $E[(X_n - E[X_n])(X_m - E[X_m])]$ is zero, so the third $E$, which barring typos is equivalent to yours. But yeah, thanks for the catch.

Comment: Ah, yes, if you remove the $E$ together with two of the brackets and introduce parentheses, it's OK :-)

Comment: Kinda late, but did I actually compute the expectation right? I know that $E[X] = \int X dP$, but I'm actually kind of confused about the $dP$.

Answer (score 1):

You're right about $\mathbb P(X_2 \in [0, 1])$ being $1/2$, not $1/4$. The *idea* of that answer is right, but it does indeed fail to be a counterexample, as you showed.

All that's happening here is that the interval $[0, 1]$ is an unlucky set to try. As an alternate approach, try the same tactic but with some interval of the form $[1-\epsilon, 1]$ where $\epsilon$ is fairly small.